# Closing JFrame of java applet using buttons on the system frame causes delay

Tags: java, applet, jframe, blocking, delay

I have written a java applet which opens a JFrame (so when run in the browser, it will popup a small new window).

The problem is, when pressing one of the buttons of the window frame, there is a slight delay (cannot move the mouse for 2 or 3 sec) before the window will close/minimize/maximize. The hidden menu actions (accessed when pressing on the icon of the window, top left) work perfectly.

In a development environment non of the problems occur.

I'm currently using jdk 1.6 update 16.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue in the mean time, maybe it will work in your situation as well.

I used to pack the interface items in the overridden "init"-function, but after doing all those in the "start"-function (also inherited from JFrame), the issue seems to be resolved.